# Visual Studio Code does not see libraries installed on the system

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, sandbox

I'm trying to use boost libraries when working with Visual Studio Code.

VS code editor can't find boost headers, and the code won't compile.

I've installed boost with `sudo apt install libboost-dev`.

The boost libraries are located in `/usr/include`, and I've added it to my active configuration.

When I go to terminal, I can see the libraries in that directory, however, when I open Visual Studio Code's terminal, and go to `/usr/include`, boost libraries are not there. And, also, that terminal can't find `apt` command.

Observation from terminal:
[image: terminal]

Observation from VS Code's terminal:
[image: vs code's terminal]

To me it looks like VS Code is running in some sort of sandbox.

When I start vscode, it runs with command

`/app/extra/vscode/code --extensions-dir=/home/user/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions --reuse-window --no-sandbox`

How do I disable the sandbox mode or install the libraries I need inside that sandbox?

Comment: VS Code is just a text editor. What do you mean by "can't find boost headers"? Are you trying to compile some code that uses Boost?

Comment: Why did you tag this with "linux"? Please read the description of the tag! Concerning "When I go to terminal, I can see the libraries in that directory, however, when I open Visual Studio Code's terminal, and go to /usr/include, boost libraries are not there.", please replace your interpretations with the actual observations, so people can at least theoretically reproduce what you did.

Comment: @Evg VS Code is a bit more, it shows me errors when I try to include boost headers into my code, and it gives me errors when I try to compile code using the editor

Comment: And how do you compile your code? Do you tell a compiler where Boost headers are located?

Comment: @Evg normally, I compile the code with cmake, and I don't have to tell the compiler where the code is located because `/usr/include` is searched by default

Comment: I wouldn't be aware of any sandboxing taking place by default. However, VS Code is notorious for its extensions, so check which ones are enabled. I could imagine that an extension runs stuff in Docker, for example. Also, baybe it helps, I have all installed extensions disabled and only enable them on a per-workspace base when they are needed there.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by re-installing the Visual Studio Code.
In pop shop, there are 2 versions of the program. First (and default) is from flathub, which is one I had installed and one that wasn't able to find boost. The other is for Pop Os (deb), and that version works fine.
I was having the issue because I didn't notice the difference when installing

Comment: Adding to this, there is also a version from the snap store, that not only solves this but also provides the `code` command to open vscode from terminal

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

> Just close VSCode completely. Make sure it's not hanging somewhere in memory. And then reopen it. Your libraries should show.